# Fill area between two overlapping shapes

Tags: python, image, binary, mask, data-preprocessing

I am trying to convert a binary mask consisting of two lines to a mask that consists of the area between the two lines.
However I am stuck and don't have an idea on how to move forward.

Here is an example of the mask I have:
[Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaBgU.png)

The goal is to make it look like this :
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpAEq.jpg)

I am using python and hope that there exists a library that manages this task. I tried plt.fill_between however I had no success with this.
The masks consists of an numpy ndarray(208,208)
The matrix looks like : [Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRCLD.png)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Can we have the matrix?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.